# Failed to start monitoring J4AXB761F692887 impossible to launch the app, why?

Tags: java, android

I have this error about the monitor.

When I launch my app it failed immediately with an error message. It is when I launch my JavaProject.

My gradle version is:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.monapp"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

And the log is

```
01/10 17:16:50: Launching 'app' on Physical Device.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.monapp/com.example.monapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 21853 on device 'asus-asus_x00qd-J4AXB761F692887'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/.example.monap: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I/.example.monap: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.monapp, PID: 21853
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6459)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6001)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5907)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:200)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6732)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxb.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.1.1:27)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.1.1:3)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6454)
... 10 more
```

Comment: what is your App ID in manifest ?

Comment: i have no app id strangely :s

Comment: did you read this https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml ?